# How to vectorize web scraping in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, vectorization, rvest

I am trying to scrap data from a website, where I have to first get a list of links from the main page, and then go into each link to scrape data. The only way I can think of to do this is through a loop.

For example:

```
library(rvest)

content <- c(rep(NA_character_,10))
for(i in 1:10){
    link <- html(links[i])
    content[i] <- html_text(html_nodes(link,"tr:nth-child(1) td"))
}
```

Here, assume that links is a character vector of urls.

This works, but it is very slow. Is there a way to speed it up?

Comment: It would be best to do everything you want to do with each page inside the loop, then throw the html away at the end of each iteration so you don't keep a huge amount in memory.  So basically dump `link` at the end of each iteration.  I don't know what the function is in `rvest`, but in `XML` it's `free()`

Comment: @RichardScriven thanks for the suggestion! hm can I use `rm()` for that?

Comment: `rm()` only removes the object from an an environment.  It does not necessarily free the memory, at least not right away.

Comment: `gc()` is the default in R

Comment: You could use `lapply` or `plyr::l*ply` but without a more complete explanation of what you're trying to do, I can't provide a complete solution